# Cannot connect to my server from my emulator

Tags: java, android, networking, httpurlconnection

I am trying to connect to my vagrant server from my android app. When I run this code:

```
 try {
            //Build the connection
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8000/test");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);



            HashMap<String, String> postDataParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
            postDataParams.put("param1", "2");
            postDataParams.put("param2", "4567");
            postDataParams.put("param3");

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            connection.connect();
            Integer responsecode = connection.getResponseCode();


            String message = "The Response Was: " + Integer.toString(responsecode);
            Log.d("MainActivity", message);
            Log.d("MainActivity", connection.getResponseMessage());
            //Is dit nodig???
            //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = (e.getMessage()==null)?"Geen message!":e.getMessage();
            Log.i("Error",msg);
        }
    }
```

I get a `404` as a response. But when I fire up a browser from my emulator and go to I get the page I want.

How could I solve this?

Comment: when you open a url in browser by just entering it in address bar, it uses GET method, while here in code you are using POST. So, try using POST method also in the browser by using REST client extension i.e. Postman for google chrome

Comment: is the server with ip 10.0.2.2 running on your local computer?, and where are you running app, on device or emulator?

Comment: @meghraj27 the server is running on my local computer. 10.0.2.2 is just a loopback to 127.0.0.1 as described in their manual The app is on the emulator

Comment: `get a 404 as a response.`. Ok. And what does that mean?

Comment: `connection.connect();`. Remove that statement. Why would you connect again after having written your data? That is impossible in the http protocol.